# Underlying method of java.util.concurrent.ScheduledFuture

Tags: java, concurrency, scheduled-tasks

I know that the `object.wait()` is the underlying method of `java.util.Timer`. Then what is the underlying method of `java.util.concurrent.ScheduledFuture`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you clarify what's meant by "`object.wait()` is the underlying method of `java.util.Timer`"?

Comment: "timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(timerTask,  startTime,  interval);" the timertask thread will wait for 'interval' milliseconds. It uses   "wait(long)" method. Then what is the method in ScheduledFuture ? wait, sleep or something else ?

Comment: ScheduledFuture is an interface, the actual behavior depends on the actual implementation you are using

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not that simple. Having a look at source of JDK `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` can answer your question (there's plenty of comments explaining how executor works).

Answer (score 0):

Use ScheduledFuture with [ScheduledExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html)

```
ScheduledExecutorService scheduledExecutorService = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(2);
scheduledFuture = scheduledExecutorService.schedulexxxx();
```

Take a look at possibilities for scheduling at [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html).

Comment: Thanks for your anticipation. I know these things scheduler.scheduleWithFixedDelay(schedule, initial, interval, TimeUnit.SECONDS), when we are giving the 'interval' which method interrupts the execution after the interval time period ?